# Wildcards in Get-QADuser

Tags: powershell, quest

How can I search for user using quest cmdlets (Get-QADUser) for accounts containing an "_" (underscore) followed by any 3 characters
for eg.

**User01_ad1, 
User55_a2d, 
User116_arr, 
User9999_1ad**

I tried following but it does seem to work:

```
Get-QADUser -LdapFilter '(samaccountname=*_???)'
```

does get-qaduser does not recognize "?" as wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single character wildcard is not available ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)). You can get accounts with `_` using `Get-QADUser` and fine-tune the results with a `-match` regex-pattern using `Where-Object`.

Ex getting all accounts that end with underscore and three chars:

```
Get-QADUser -SamAccountName "*_*" | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -match '_\w{3}$' }
```

Comment: Got it thx, just one follow up question though, which one would work faster, your method or this: #Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 10000 | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -like '*_???'}

Comment: My solution is faster. Regex (`-match`) is faster than `-like`, but it won't matter unless `Get-QADUser` returns thousands of accounts, which your unfiltered query in the comment probably will. If you use filter on `Get-QADUser` to limit the accounts to process with `where-object`, then `-match \ -like` won't matter as much.

Comment: understood, once again thx a ton for response. Much appreciated! :)